# Slice notation in python - need clarification on a code snippet

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and while reading about slice notation, I came across the following code snippet. I was able to understand and use it in very simple examples, but I wasn't able to grasp its usage in the following example. Any explanation will really help!

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a[1:1] = [3,4,5]
>>> print a
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]

>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a[0:1] = [3,4,5]
>>> print a
[3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a[n:m] = b
# is essentially* equivalent to
a = a[:n] + b + a[m:]
```

and you could read this as "replace `a[n:m]` with `b`" (since `a = a[:n] + a[n:m] + a[m:]`).

**actually slicing mutates the list **in-place** (that is, `id(a)` remains unchanged) which will usually be preferable (wheras setting `a=` creates our new `a` at a different memory location).*

So in your examples:

```
a = [1,2]
#a[1:1] = [3,4,5]
a = a[:1] + [3,4,5] + a[1:]
#   [1]               [2]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 2]

a = [1,2]
#a[0:1] = [3,4,5]
a = a[:0] + [3,4,5] + a[1:]
#   []                [2]
[3, 4, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Does this modify the underlying list object directly? If so, your equivalence isn't quite equivalent. Probably worth a note either way. It's a good aide to understanding, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`a[1:1]` is an empty slice at the position between the first and second elements in the list.
So `a[1:1] = [3,4,5]` means "insert the elements `3,4,5` after the first element of the list".

`a[0:1]` is the slice from the first element up to (but excluding) the second element in the list.
So `a[0:1] = [3,4,5]` means "replace the first element of the list with the elements `3,4,5`".

Perhaps this visualization helps:

```
| h | e | l | l | o |    <-- string "hello"
0   1   2   3   4   5    <-- slice positions
^---^                    <-- slice [0:1]: "h"
    ^                    <-- slice [1:1]: ""
```